# Because of the fact that $exp:\mathfrak{so}(n)\to SO(n)$ is surjective it follows that $SO(n)$ is connected?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

**Because of the fact that $exp:\mathfrak{so}(n)\to SO(n)$ is surjective it follows that $SO(n)$ is connected?**

I am looking at a proof that $SO(n)$ is connected and in this show that the function $exp:\mathfrak{so}(n)\to SO(n)$ is surjective, because it is only necessary to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Suppose it is not connected. Then the two components must be clopen by hausdorff property of $SO(n)$. By continuity lift the image back to $\mathcal{so}(n)$ which is connected. That is contradiction.

Comment: It is even path connected, since we can draw a path from the identity to any element $e^A \in SO(n)$ by the function $f: [0, 1] \to SO(n)$, $f(t) = e^{tA}$.

Comment: @user45765 
What does clopen mean? 
Could you explain your idea better?

Comment: @Nash Clopen means both open and closed. The exp map is continuous as it is smooth. Assume $SO(n)=U\cup V$ with $U,V$ open and disjoint. Then $U$ is clopen. Then $U,V$'s inverse image in $so(n)$ are clopen at the same time by continuity. Then their inverse images have no intersection which implies inverse images form disjoint union of $so(n)$. However, $so(n)$ is connected. Thus, it is contradiction. You do not have to follow this proof by contradiction.

Comment: @user45765 
That's perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: @user45765: How do we know the inverse is continuous and/or that it exists, other than locally?